# Scaling Scene Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a BIM building design and a custom model in forge scene. I moved the custom model 1 unit on the X axis with the following method `mesh.matrix.setPosition(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0))`. I want that the displacement of 1 unit is equal to 1 meter.
My question :

1. How do I do this on Autodesk Forge ?
2. In more detail, how do I determine the scale of the Forge scene in meters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading your Forge model with the `applyScaling` property set to `meters`, for example, like so:

```js
async function loadModel(viewer, urn) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
            const viewable = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
            const options = {
                applyScaling: 'meters'
            };
            viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewable, options)
                .then(resolve)
                .catch(reject);
        }
        function onDocumentLoadFailure(code) {
            reject(`Could not load document (${code}).`);
        }
        Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load('urn:' + urn, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
    });
}
```

That way, if the loaded model is defined in different units, the viewer will scale it so that 1 unit in its geometry will represent 1 meter.